# Trying to make TinyMCE dom.replace work in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
var dom = tinymce.get( 'content' ).dom;

var newel = $( '<p/>' ).html( 'some html with text' );
var oldel = dom.get( dom.select( 'oldelID' ) );

dom.replace( newel.get(0), oldel );
                   ^^^^^
```

I get the following error message : **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

But, both newel and oldel are Node type objects.

Do you I need to insert the new el object into the DOM to work?

Comment: It is a jQuery object, not a Node.

Comment: Okay, then I will try to add it into the dom and then run the replace fnc; however there must be a better solution but for now I just want it make it work.

Comment: You can javascript object from jQuery using `get(0)`

Comment: Perfect that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter 1 that is a jQuery object, for use in the replaceChild function, you need to convert it into the javascript object.

This can be achieved using [get function](https://api.jquery.com/get/) from jQuery.

```
var dom = tinymce.get( 'content' ).dom;

var newel = $( '<p/>' ).html( 'some html with text' );
var oldel = dom.get( dom.select( 'oldelID' ) );

dom.replace( newel.get(0), oldel );
```